# Java: Annotated Annotations (and passing values)

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have a annotation that does include several other annotations, pretty much like this one here:

```
@Component // Spring Component
@Interface OsgiService { boolean isFactory() }
```

meaning that all classes annotated with `@OsgiService` shall automatically also be annotated as `@Component`. Which works fine.

Now however, I'd like to add another annotation, that has a parameter which is dependent of the `isFactory` parameter of `@OsgiService`.

```
@Component // Spring Component
@Scope(isFactory() ? "prototype" : "singleton")
@Interface OsgiService { boolean isFactory() }
```

Which does not work. However, as `isFactory` property of an annotation requires to be a static value, shouldn't it be possible to have something like this?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible.

You can create two annotations: `@OsgiService` and `@OsgiServiceFactory`